# Cannot pass data with service in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-guards

> PS:
>
> When I talk to my colleague, they told me to get Role's right with
> once request, if it is not authenticated then reject, else return the
> data to frond-end. But, I got stuck in use Angular2's Guard.

Apps do:

1. Access my routes, and `Guard` prevent it, the Guard send a request to server to check its auth.
2. Request the `server`, when server return `statue:true`and`data:[somedatas]` then **set data with module's dataService**, and resolve `true` for canActivate.
3. Init the target component, in `constructor`, use `dataService` to get the meta data.

But, I failed to pass the data from my Guard to Service. I provide them in same module. Here's my code:

Module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DocsComponent,
    DocsListComponent, // this is the component I will access
    BarButtonsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DocsRouting,
    // ShareModule
  ],
  providers:[
    DocsGuard,
    DocsDataService // here I provide my dataService that I mentioned before
  ],
  exports: [DocsComponent],
})
```

routes:

```
const DOCS_ROUTES:Routes = [
  {path:'',redirectTo:'doclist',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'',component:DocsComponent,children:[
    {path:'doclist', component: DocsListComponent}
  ], canActivate:[DocsGuard] } // use `Guard` to prevent it.
];
```

My dataService.ts:

```
  private doclist:Doclist[] ; // this

  getData(){
    return this.doclist; 
  }

  setData(obj){
    this.doclist = obj;
  }

  getDocAuth(): Observable<any>{
    let options = new RequestOptions({
      withCredentials:true
    });
    // ...using get request
    return this.http.get(this.docUrl,options)
    // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
      .map((res:Response) =>res.json())
      //...errors if any
      .catch((error:any) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

Guard.ts:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean>{
    let subject = new Subject<boolean>();
    let that = this;
    this.docsDataService.getDocAuth().subscribe(
      res=>{
        if(res.status){
          // Here I want to pass data to my component, I failed.
          that.docsDataService.setData(res.data); 
          subject.next(true);
        }else{
          subject.next(false);
        }
        console.log("next: returning true");
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        subject.next(false);
      }
    );
    return subject.asObservable().first();
  }
```

Thanks.

======================supplement 2017-02-17 17：34======================

Appmodule routes:

```
const APP_ROUTERS:Routes = [
  { path:'',component:JwLoginComponent},
  { path:'main',loadChildren:'app/main/main.module#MainModule'},
  { path:'**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Main routes:

```
const MAIN_ROUTES : Routes = [
  {path:'main',component:MainComponent,canActivate:[DataGuard]},
  {path:'share',loadChildren:'app/common/share.module#ShareModule'}
];
```

Share routes:

```
const SHARE_ROUTES:Routes = [
  {path:'',redirectTo:'docs',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'',component: ShareComponent,children:[
    { path:'docs',loadChildren:'app/docs/docs.module#DocsModule'},  
    // Question here: cannot get data from service set in DocsModule, but in MainModule or AppModule as providers.
    { path:'mic',loadChildren:'app/mic/mic.module#MicModule'},
    { path:'user-manage',loadChildren:'app/user-manage/user-manage.module#UserManageModule'},
    { path:'settings',loadChildren:'app/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule'},
    { path:'logs',loadChildren:'app/logs/logs.module#LogsModule'}
  ]},

];
```

I found I provide the `DocService` in MainModule or AppModule, I can got data from @mxii code. But, when I set this service into DocsModule or ShareModule, I cannot got data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demo should help:

```js
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  public data = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  public setData(data: any) {
    this.data.next(data);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  public validate(user, pass): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of({ test: 'data' }).delay(123);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class DocsGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _dataService: DataService) {}

  canActivate() {
    return this._authService.validate('user', 'pass').map(data => {
      console.log('GUARD: auth data:', data);

      // .. do something ..

      if (!data || data.anyThing === 'anyValue') {
        console.log('GUARD: auth WRONG');
        return false; // not authenticated !
      }

      console.log('GUARD: auth OKAY, set data..');

      this._dataService.setData(data);

      return true;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return Observable.of(false); // protect route !
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
    {{ _data | async | json }}
  `,
})
export class DocsListComponent {

  private _data: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._data = this._dataService.data;
    this._data.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('DocsListComponent: something changed', data);
    });
  }
}
```

live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/PGsTD3Ma9yDidhxEgot3?p=preview

**UPDATE**

Your Service should only be included **ONCE!!**

You have to `provide` your Service to the "highest" NgModule.

Otherwise every NgModule will create a NEW instance of your Service..

If it's only `provided` to one NgModule, its a singleton!

Maybe you have to create functions like `forRoot` and `forChild` like the RouterModule does.

Comment: Hi, @mxli, thanks. I got from my console: GUARD: auth OKAY, set data.. But, after init: DocsListComponent: something changed null, the data is gone. PS: When I debug my `canActivate` function, I notice the data got from server is a json object.

Comment: Please show that JSON object and your modified Guard.

Comment: data
Objectdata: Array[10]size: 10,status: true,total: "63"__proto__: Object——Copy from my chrome console

Comment: and replace `.map((res:Response) =>res.json())` with this: `.map((res:Response) => { console.log(res.text()); return res; }).map((res:Response) =>res.json())`

Comment: @mxli I change my DocsService providers from DocsModule to AppModule. And set: `this._data.subscribe(data => {console.log('DocsListComponent: something changed', data); this.doclist = data.data;});`, I got my data.

Comment: That's great! Any other questions?

Comment: I update my question, why should I provide the dataService in the parent module?

Comment: See my updated answer. Its very important to `provide` your service ONLY ONCE! :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This is my [code](https://github.com/kanlidy/JianweiTV/blob/dev/src/app/main/main.module.ts#L21). (1) I knew I should import the Service once, but this DocService only use in this module not anywhere else for fetch data to its child components. So, I want the DocModule to provide it, not its parent module -MainModule or AppModule (2) I use Modules for lazy loading, so I wonder whether the DocModule affect the DocGuard to pass data to DocService. Before the DocGuard, the route cannot navigate in the DocModule, so there's no instance of DocSerice.

Comment: [Module providers can't be used by design](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14207) I found a answer from angular community of github. As you said, "that provides services should be imported to the AppModule via forRoot". I will update my app code, and back.