# BehaviorSubject in angular returning null

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject, canactivate

I am using BehaviorSubject to store user info on login. For some weird reason, the user info returned by BehaviorSubject is `null` in AuthGuard that gets activated for my endpoint. Please help me understand what am I missing.

I have already tried to return the subject as observable, subcribe to the subject, ReplaySubject. Nothing seems to work and the user info is always null in auth guard. I have moved the AuthService provider declaration between app module and the service component. That also didn't help. Until the call goes to auth guard, the flow is normal where the user info is set. As soon as the auth guard is called, the user info is lost.

user reg: This is step where user logs in

```
 onSubmit() {
    this.document.location.href = environment.callbackUrl;
  }
```

login component: This component sets the user info

```
this.authService.setUserInfo(user);
if (user.id_token!=null && user.role!=null && user.isLoggedIn){
  this.router.navigate(['/view-main/datalogger-list']);
}
```

auth service

```
userSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserInfo> = new BehaviorSubject<UserInfo>(null);

setUserInfo(user: UserInfo){
  if(user && user !=null){
    this.userSubject.next(user);
  }
}

getUserInfo() {
    return this.userSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

auth guard: here the user info is null

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    debugger
    let userInfo:UserInfo;

    this.authService.getUserInfo().subscribe(user => {
      console.log('Evaluating in auth guard');
      console.log('User: ', user);
      //if user is logged in and role info is available from database.
      if(user && user!=null 
          && user.role!=null && user.role.trim().length>0 
          && user.wwid!=null && user.wwid.trim().length>0){
        // allow user
        userInfo = user;
        return true;
      }
      // TO-DO user logged in but do not have information from database -How i will knwo this?
      else if(user && user!=null 
              && user.wwid!=null && user.wwid.trim().length>0
              && (user.role==null || user.role=='undefined') ){
        this.router.navigate(['welcome']);
        return false;
      }else{
        // redirect user to oidc urls
        this.router.navigate(['welcome']);
        return false;
      }
    })
    return false;
  }
```

Expected: Return current user info
Actual: Returns null

Comment: `this.document.location.href = environment.callbackUrl;` I think this line is reloading the application from the ground up. Are you sure you are not experiencing a full reload? when navigating from one page to the other in Angular, you should use the Angular router.

Comment: Where are you calling `setUserInfo(user)`?

Comment: Please share more of your code or describe the full context. It is obvious that you retrieve null since the canActivate guard is called even before user details get added. You need to triage what calls it (Page load?)

Comment: Sorry, the canActivate method, as your definition says, should return boolean, not *UserInfo*

Comment: @A.Chiesa, the callbackUrl is to all the IDP and the login component sets the user info after that call. So I think there is no reload happening there

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the root of your problem in your `canActivate` method, is that at the moment is called, you still don´t have the information of the user, and as you have initialized the `BehaviorSubject` with **null** value, this is exactly what you get there.

Instead of returning the value, I would return the the userSubject as an Observable, and subscribe to it on your `canActivate` method:

```
userSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserInfo> = new BehaviorSubject<UserInfo>(null);
 setUserInfo(user: UserInfo){
    if(user && user !=null){
      this.userSubject.next(user);
    }
  }
 getUser() {
    return this.userSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

And the guard:

```
 canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    let userInfo:UserInfo;  
    this.authService.getUser().subscribe(user => userInfo = user);
    return true;
}
```

Hope that helps you!

;)

Comment: You've missed the return in your `canActivate()` method and the equation of the userInfo is not an equation but an assignement

Comment: Can't you just subscribe to BehaviorSubject? why would we need here "asObservable()"?

Comment: @DanielHabenicht, nope I didn´t missed. I just modified the example provided, which is not returning anything. I think it is not completed, and he also wants to do so something the **user** before returning...

Comment: @SergeyRudenko It is a common practice to don´t expose the Subject, and keep it as private in the service. Exposing the Observable, you will not need anymore to `complete` the BehaviorSubject manually, and use it as other Observable.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but it's not valid Code. Somebody looking at your example would run into the next error because canActicate never returns anything. Can you add the "do something with it" as comment to your code and make it valid?

Comment: @DanielHabenicht you are totally right, gotcha. I have edited the response to return *true*. Thanks!

Comment: @AJT82 yep, this won't work. MiguelSsRrR should return a mapped observable as the example does not respect the asynchronous call.

Comment: I updated the code as suggested by @MiguelSsSRrR, but still the user info returned is null.

Comment: @DanielHabenicht, could you please explain more one returning a mapped observable? May be I am missing that. Thanks

Comment: Like `canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.getUser().map(user => { 
       return user.loggedIn
    });
}`

Comment: @scu this should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366316/using-behaviorsubject-in-auth-guards-canactivate

Comment: Yes. I changed it to ```this.authService.getUserInfo().pipe(map(user => { userInfo = user;return userInfo.isLoggedIn;}));```. Still it wouldn't work. While debugging I see that after routing when the guard gets activated the user info subject gets initialized to null which is the initial value.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. All the comments were helpful and my issue was the auth service was getting initialized in my nav component. And that's the reason it always had null value. This answer helped me think in that direction: [Cannot pass data with service in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292115/cannot-pass-data-with-service-in-angular2)